# How to properly log an error and then re-raise an exception

Tags: python

Is the following the correct pattern for logging something and re-raising the error -- specifically, just using a blank `raise` without anything after it? Is there a more explicit way to do that?

```
try: #MySQL
    conn = pymysql.connect(host=HOST, user=USER, passwd=PASS, db=NAME)
except pymysql.err.OperationalError:
    logger.error('Make sure a separate credentials file has been sourced.')
    raise
```

Comment: This *is* the explicit way to do it…!?

Comment: @deceze I mean something like `raise RuntimeError("Some message")`.

Comment: Why raise a different error?